# How to get next item in for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to get the next item in an arraylist. I have a list of strings that I am trying to get the next item and if the next item does not exist it sets it to the last item (I already got the last item)

```
for (int i = 0; i < stops.size(); i++) {
 String stop = stops.get(i);
 Optional<String> nextStop = (stops.size() > i) ? Optional.of(stops.get(i + 1)) : lastStop;
```

Is what I have tried but for some reason it is throwing the index out of bounds exception

I would expect it to get the next item if the list has more items than the current but it fails due to an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to have fixed it. Care to explain as to why it works that way so I can understand why your solution fixed it?

Comment: Conversely you can also use `stops.size() - 1 > i`.

Comment: Ah makes sense! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop to iterate over the contents of a list, and then do an extra check to see if you're at the last element, like this:

```
String lastStop = "lastStop";
int element = 0;
List<String> stops = new ArrayList<>();
for (String stop : stops) {
    boolean isLastStop = (element == stops.size());
    if (isLastStop) {
        stop = lastStop;
    }

    System.out.println("stop: " + stop);

    element++;
}
```

or create a sublist of the main one, ignoring the final element, then do one extra step to process `finalStop`:

```
List<String> sublist = stops.subList(0, stops.size() - 1);
for (String stop: sublist) {
    // do something with stop
}
// after, do something with lastStop
```

Answer (score 0):

> (I already got the last item)

Then why don't you simply remove this item from the list

```java
stops.remove(lastStop);
```